# Выбор системы для загрузки

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot

Имеется 2 жестких диска, на первом установлена Windows 7, на втором Linux Ubuntu. Оба подключены. В BIOS поставил загрузку со второго жесткого диска. При включении, естественно, грузится Linux. Как сделать так чтобы во время загрузки запрашивало выбор ОС? Я слышал что есть, если не ошибаюсь граб. Мне в эту сторону копать?

Comment: А у вас grub на линуксе установлен, и он просто не показывает меню? Или ещё не установлен?

Comment: @VladD ещё не установлен, я с Unix like системами пока ещё на вы.

Comment: Точно не установлен? Проверьте, он по идее должен устанавливаться автоматически. http://serverfault.com/q/61400

Comment: @VladD вечером проверю.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько знаю, да. Граб умеет запускать и Линукс, и Винду. Поищите статьи [здесь](http://ubuntu.ru/) или [здесь](http://compizomania.blogspot.com/)

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас посмотрю.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).

Answer (score 2):

В Ubuntu в консоли (Ctrl+Alt+T) наберите

```
sudo update-grub2
```

и перезагрузите компьютер. При загрузке компьютера секунд на 10 должно появится меню, в котором стрелками вверх/вниз можно выбрать операционную систему, Windows 7 будет в конце списка.

Answer (score 1):

Изучать и экспериментировать с Linux-ом лучше в виртуальной машине.